# Add received cookies to a cookie template file in PHP cUrl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a file with a bunch of cookies called cookie.txt and I wanted to add the received cookies and used them combined.

if I do:

```
    $cookie_file= __DIR__.'/cookie.txt';
    @unlink($cookie_file);
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file
```

I will only use the received cookies and if I don't unlink the file I'll only use the template without the received cookies.

How can I append what I receive in CookieJar instead of replacing?